# How can I unzip a file with applescript and shell, but without receiving the following error?

Tags: javascript, macos, automation, applescript, automator

I'm new to AppleScript and I am currently working on automating some Finder work processes using AppleScript.

At the end of the script, I want AppleScript to do a shell command, which unzips a .zip file.

If I manually enter the shell script " unzip Users/1/2/3 " in the terminal, the zip is successfully unzipped.

Sadly AppleScript returns an error: `error:  cannot create abc.jpg Permission denied" number 50`

It would be very nice if someone could help me with fixing this error since I haven't got much experience with AppleScript.

```
set raw_folder to "/Users/abc/Desktop/1/2/3/4"
set editing_folder to "/Users/abc/Desktop/1/2/3/5"

tell application "Finder" to sort every file of folder (raw_folder as POSIX file) by modification date

tell application "Finder" to set theFile to (item 1 of result) as alias

tell application "Finder" to move theFile to (editing_folder as POSIX file)

tell application "Finder" to set theFile to (item 1 of folder (editing_folder as POSIX file))

do shell script "unzip" & " /Users/abc/Desktop/1/2/3/5/abc.zip"
```

Comment: You need another double-quote at the end of the last line.

Comment: I don't think you should need to use `do shell script` to unzip a file, Finder knows how to uncompress zip files.

Comment: Ok, what command can I use instead of a shell script ?

Comment: The double quote actually exists in the original script. I didnt copy it correctly

Comment: Hmm, I can't find a command. I assumed there would be one, since you can double-click on a zip file and it will expand it. But "open filename" doesn't work.

Comment: hmm ok, thx anyways. I think you could maybe use some keystrokes or key codes, but i'd also prefer a solution without ui programming 

Comment: You can just `tell application "Finder" to open file "some:file:path"`, which should launch the **Archive Utility** application to unzip the file.  Note that the Finder doesn't use POSIX paths, so you don't need to coerce the Finder items unless you are going to be using them with a shell script.

Comment: Ok, I just tried it and I received another error.  Now the file somehow "could not be read" :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppleScript's `do shell script` command works with a default environment that does not load settings you expect when you work in a shell in terminal. The problem here is that the default directory of this stripped-down shell is '/', meaning you're trying to unzip your archive at the root level, and running into permissions issues. You should explicitly point to an output directory with the -d option:

```
do shell script "unzip -d /Users/abc/Desktop/ /Users/abc/Desktop/1/2/3/5/abc.zip"
```

This will unzip the contents of your file to the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

The **Finder** `open` command can handle unzipping files, which is normally done by the default **Archive Utility** application.  This method unzips the file to the same directory - not sure where your error is coming from, but unless a working directory has been set, the `unzip` shell utility will unzip to the base/root user directory.

```
set theFile to (choose file) -- get the zip file

tell application "Finder" to open theFile
-- or --
do shell script "cd ~/Desktop;  /usr/bin/unzip " & quoted form of POSIX path of theFile -- unzip to current working directory
```

Note that the **Finder** doesn't use POSIX paths, so you don't need to coerce Finder items unless you are going to be using them with shell commands.